# ¿Cómo solucionar error 404 NOT FOUND con Ajax y consulta php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, modal

en mi código tengo una DataTable con la que imprimo valores desde mi base de datos. Ahora le estoy añadiendo una ventana modal con bootstrap para introducir datos a una de mis tablas, ahora bien, capturo y envío los datos de la ventana modal usando Ajax, pero cuando ejecuto mi código y oprimo el botón de registrar que está dentro del modal me aparece en consola este error (en la imagen de abajo) y no me envía los datos al php donde se realiza la consulta:

Cabe aclarar que la conexión con el script donde está el ajax es exitosa, ya que, ejecuta sin problemas las validaciones que incluí en los campos del modal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registrar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Registro de Anexo</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="formanexo">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="numfianza" class="col-form-label">Numero de Fianza:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numfianza">
            <label for="" id="lblfianza"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="numanexo" class="col-form-label">Numero de Anexo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numanexo">
            <label for="" id="lblanexo"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="desde" class="col-form-label">Desde:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="desde">
            <label for="" id="lbldesde"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="hasta" class="col-form-label">Hasta:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="hasta">
            <label for="" id="lblhasta"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="monto" class="col-form-label">Monto:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto">
            <label for="" id="lblmonto"></label>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
         
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="respuesta"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> 
      
      
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      
    
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi script donde está el método Ajax:

```
$("#formanexo").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var numfianza=$("#numfianza").val();
    var numanexo=$("#numanexo").val();
    var desde=$("#desde").val();
    var hasta=$("#hasta").val();
    var monto=$("#monto").val();

    var parametros={"numfianza":numfianza,"numanexo":numanexo,"desde":desde,"hasta":hasta,"monto":monto};    
    if (numfianza=='') {
        $("#lblfianza").html("<span style='color:red'>Complete este campo</span>");
        $("#numfianza").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (numanexo=='') {
        $("#lblanexo").html("<span style='color:red'>Complete este campo</span>");
        $("#numanexo").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (desde=='') {
        $("#lbldesde").html("<span style='color:red'>Complete este campo</span>");
        $("#desde").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (hasta=='') {
        $("#lblhasta").html("<span style='color:red'>Complete este campo</span>");
        $("#hasta").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (monto=='') {
        $("#lblmonto").html("<span style='color:red'>Complete este campo</span>");
        $("#monto").focus();
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"./registro.php",
        method:"POST",

        data:parametros,

        success: function(data){
            $("#registrar").modal('hide');
            $("#respuesta").html(data);
            $("#formanexo").trigger('reset');
        }
    })
```

Consulta php:

```
<?php

include_once("conn.php");



$numfianza=$_POST["numfianza"];
$numanexo=$_POST["numanexo"];
$desde=$_POST["desde"];
$hasta=$_POST["hasta"];
$monto=$_POST["monto"];
var_dump($_POST);
$sql="INSERT INTO anexos_auxiliares (N_FIANZA, N_DE_ANEXO, DESDE_, HASTA_, MONTO_BS) VALUES ('$numfianza','$numanexo', '$desde', '$hasta', '$monto')";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if ($resultado) {
    echo"<p class='text-success'>Se registro correctamente</p>";
}
else {
    echo"<p class='text-success'>No se ha podido registrar</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola buena tardes, revisa la ubicacion del archivo, tendras que modificar el path para que lo pueda encontrar ../

Comment: Buenas tardes, el archivo php lo coloqué en la misma carpeta del script para ver si así no me daba error y coloqué el url como "registro.php" y aún así me da el mismo error.

Comment: entonces solo ponle el nombre url:"registro.php", asi, ya hiciste la prueba?

Comment: correcto, lo hice tal cual y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: tendras imagenes de las rutas de tu proyecto para tratar de replicarlo o si lo tienes en github y lo trabajamos juntos

Comment: en **registro.php** puedes verificar si te llegan los datos usando la función `print_r($_POST);die();` después de la etiqueta de apertura `<?php`, el resultado se verá en pantalla o en la consola del navegador.

Comment: @Josebas, asegurate que el nombre del sea exactamente `registro.php`, sin mayúsculas, espacios, ni nada.

Comment: Gracias por sus consejos, ya solucioné el error. Tuve que colocar la dirección url completa, es decir, "http:// localhost/proyecto/php/registro.php" y así si encontró el archivo php y ejecutó la consulta exitosamente.

Answer (score 0):

ya logré solucionarlo por si a alguien le llega a interesar. Tuve que colocar la url en mi ajax de forma completa, es decir:

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/responsive/php/registro.php",
        method:"POST",

        data:parametros,

        success: function(data){
            $("#registrar").modal('hide');
            $("#respuesta").html(data);
            $("#formanexo").trigger('reset');
        }
    });
```